# Stored Procedure with increasing number

Tags: sql-server

anyone can give a tutorial or complete script for this in mssql:

```
exec up_AddMyCashItemByItem 'usernum','0','1','1','1','0'
```

i want to usernum automatically until the last line count!

so automatically should do this.

```
 exec up_AddMyCashItemByItem '1','0','1','1','1','0'
 exec up_AddMyCashItemByItem '2','0','1','1','1','0'
 exec up_AddMyCashItemByItem '3','0','1','1','1','0'
```

till last line of given table reach!

Comment: try re-write you  question , or what is the outcome you want

Comment: I want to get an easier procedure to auto repeat

Comment: Do you want to run the proc for each row in a recordset or do you just have a start and end number you want to loop between?

Comment: yep exactly..
only 1 value should be grow 1,2,3...x
all others same in procedure! but it need run approx 4000 times and dont know how i can loop this..

Comment: You are requesting a result in mysql but have the question tagged as sql-server.  Which is correct?

Comment: @KennethFisher - no, the OP is asking for an answer in m**s**sql

Comment: @BaloghSándor You mentioned "till last line of given table reach". Does this mean that usernum is a column of a table and you would like the values of this column to be the variable parameter of the exec of the stored procedure?

Comment: @nurdglaw Duh, I misread it.  Feel rather silly now.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @currentVal INT = 1, @maxVal INT = 4000;

WHILE @currentVal <= @maxVal
BEGIN
    EXEC up_AddMyCashItemByItem @currentVal,'0','1','1','1','0';
    SET @currentVal = @currentVal + 1;
END;
```